# Error while opscode-manage-ctl reconfigure?

Tags: chef-infra

After I have installed the opscode-manage version 1.6.2-1, I am going to execute the reconfigure command which is opscode-manage-ctl reconfigure. It shows the error. Any ideas? I am using open source chef server 11.1.6-1.
I am looking the file  /opt/opscode-manage/embedded/cookbooks/opscode-manage/recipes/default.rb.But why it shows this error?

```
Recipe: opscode-manage::default
  * private_chef_addon[opscode-manage] action create (up to date)

================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /opt/opscode-manage/embedded/cookbooks/opscode-manage/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================


NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /opt/opscode-manage/embedded/cookbooks/opscode-manage/recipes/default.rb:28:in `from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/opt/opscode-manage/embedded/cookbooks/opscode-manage/recipes/default.rb:

 21:  private_chef_addon 'opscode-manage' do
 22:    action :nothing
 23:  end.run_action(:create)
 24:  
 25:  #
 26:  # We're gonna check if webui1 is enabled, and bail if it is
 27:  # since we run on the same port
 28>> if node['private_chef']['opscode-webui']['enable']
 29:    Chef::Application.fatal!("opscode-webui is enabled on this node, not installing opscode-manage.")
 30:  
 31:  end
 32:  
 33:  include_recipe 'opscode-manage::config'
 34:  include_recipe 'opscode-manage::redis'
 35:  
 36:  class Chef::Resource::RunitService
 37:    include Manage::Helpers




Running handlers:
[2015-01-19T14:38:47+05:30] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete

[2015-01-19T14:38:47+05:30] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-01-19T14:38:47+05:30] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/opscode-manage/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 4.674777774 seconds
[2015-01-19T14:38:47+05:30] ERROR: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
[2015-01-19T14:38:47+05:30] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opscode Manage is not compatible with Chef Server 11 of any variety. How did you even install it?

Comment: rpm -ivh opscode-manage-1.6.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm. Then how can I do it?

Comment: You have to upgrade to Chef Server 12.

Comment: chef-server-ctl upgrade . Is this command is enough for upgrade my open source chef server?

Comment: No, it is a fairly complex procedure and way out of scope for this question. Please consult the almighty Google.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I faced on `Debian 9` with the opcode installation. My chef-server version is `12.17.5`. And I
fixed it by downloading the `chef-manage installer` package and then installing it.

```
$ wget https://packages.chef.io/files/stable/chef-manage/2.5.8/ubuntu/14.04/chef-manage_2.5.8-1_amd64.deb

$ dpkg -i chef-manage_2.5.8-1_amd64.deb

$ chef-server-ctl reconfigure
```

Hope this helps someone...!